# Pass $_SESSION to next statement

Tags: php, html

I developing a Intranet and I'm a bit stuck with allowing access for individual users. All works fine when I limit the access to an element, if that element in at the bottom/last element. I need this to usable where ever I want. If you are in the Directors group, get the element. If you are in the All group only, you get nothing. Any help would be great.

The HTML:

```
.....
<?php include('admin/Directors.php');
  echo 'foooooo':
?>
....
<?php include('admin/All.php');
  echo 'baaaar':
?>
...
```

The PHP (Directors.php):

```
<?php
  session_start();
    $allowed_users = array('mark','joe','allan');
      if(!in_array($_SESSION['user'],$allowed_users)) die('');
?>
```

From wat I understand is happening here is that its reading the Directors.php file and applying it to entire HTML file.

Comment: Do those two really need to be included at the same time?

Comment: Simply don't `die`, but instead `return`? Or reverse the condition and do `if (in_array(...)): ?><div>director stuff...`…?

Comment: Did the provided solution work?

Answer (score 0):

Try this In your `Directors.php`:

```
session_start();
$allowed_users = array('mark','joe','allan');
return in_array($_SESSION['user'],$allowed_users));
```

And this in your html:

```
$allowed = include('admin/Directors.php');
if($allowed)
{
  echo 'foooooo';
}
```

Instead of killing script with `die()` simply return the evaluation value check it in your html. But if there is other stuff in `Director.php` you can do this.

Try this In your `Directors.php`:

```
session_start();
$allowed_users = array('mark','joe','allan');
$allowed =in_array($_SESSION['user'],$allowed_users));
```

And this in your html:

```
include('admin/Directors.php');
if($allowed)
{
  echo 'foooooo';
}
```